# How to set AWS SNS mobile push notifications through CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sns

I want to add CloudFormation code to setup Mobile Push notifications but can't find any way to do it. If you have any suggestions, it would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You can create a custom resource in CloudFormation for that.